# Xamarin App doesn't run on Android Phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I developed a Xamarin Forms application, I built the .apk file and installed it on my Android phone. It installs successfully but when I try to open the application it is stuck, only the loading screen appears and I need to restart the phone to open that again, `.apk` is created without any errors.

Comment: pretty sure that's cause it is called xama`rin`, not xamar`ian` :)

Comment: when you generate .APK did you put required permissions to Manifest?

Comment: Are you debug testing on all the API levels that your app supports? i.e. Using the correct API calls for the the API level, declaring the correct permissions in the manifest AND requesting/using runtime-based permissions for the API levels are use them? Are you release configuration testing on those API levels also?

Comment: Are you sure you grabbed the signed apk? It's easy to grab the non-signed one and that could cause the issues you are experiencing

Comment: Have you tried building and running an "empty" app (the very basic one from the templates), doe sthat work? Is there any initialization code that might hang? Without further detail (code, [mcve]) it's hard to tell, what the problem is. Please see [ask].

Comment: Please provide an `adb logcat` attempting to install and run your application. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/